# Why is this code giving me so much trouble/how can I do this better?

Tags: html, css, footer

Two problems to start off with:

1. The links in my footer aren't linking;
2. CSS isn't effecting their font color.

Live example [here](http://viddir.com).

Answer (score 1):

To make links clickable:

Add z-index:1 and position:relative for #wrapper2

Remove z-index:-1 for #footer

To apply the color:

```
#footerlinks a {
    color: white;
}
```

The color is not working because you set the color for #footerlinks and then for a:link element. The a:link is more important than #footerlinks so it sets the color.